# How does cin detect eol vs an invalid character

Tags: c++

**Problem :**

*Write a program to calculate the addition of  integers and print the output.*

**Input Format:**

*Line 1: Integers delimited by space*

**Output:**

*The output consists of a single integer which corresponds to addition, followed by a new line.
Line 1 addition of numbers*

**Sample Input and Output:**

Input 1:

3 4 5 6 7

Output 1:

25

Input 2 :

3 5 a b 7

Output:

Invalid Input

---

So , i've tried many approaches , but nothing seems to work

This was my last attempt before i gave up

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){

    int i;
    int sum=0;

     cin>>i;
      while(isdigit(i)){

        sum+=i;
       cin>>i;
      }
      if(!isdigit(i)) cout<<"Invalid Input";
      else cout<<sum;


  return 0;
```

---

Big thanks to everyone who helped ...

I realized that i was using isdigit the wrong way ...
A slight modification in code did the trick

**Final solution that works** :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){

    char i;
    int sum=0;


      while(cin>>i){

       if(!isdigit(i)) {
                cout<<"Invalid Input";
                return 0;
       }
        sum+=(i-'0');

      }
         cout<<sum;


  return 0;
}
```

*Let me explain what i finally did .... I took all the input as char 
I let (cin>>i)ensure that the inputs are read till EOL.

I added a condition to check if the input i got was not a digit ( if that happened , i would print "Invalid Input" and break out of the loop..else i would get the int value equivalent to char by doing ('0'- i) ,add that to sum  and  continue looping till the end of the loop and print the sum*

Another solution if there are double digits present ( will work only in c++11 onward )

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){

    string i;
    int sum=0;


      while(cin>>i){
       try{

          sum+= stoi(i);

       } 
       catch(...){

           cout<<"Undefined";
           return 0;
       }

      }
         cout<<sum;


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`isdigit(i)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - thanks , checking on cppref

Comment: Isn't the reference elaboate enough? You already have numbers when using `cin>>i;`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - thanks , followed your advise and took the input as char . With a little manipulation of code , got the desired result

Comment: Your title has no apparent connection with your question.

Comment: @EJP -  i was confused about the way to decipher between a char input an an EOL using cin ... understanding that did solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, the statement

```
 cin>>i;
```

reads a number from the standard input stream. So an input of

```
 3
```

results in an integer value `3`.

The `isdigit(i)` function checks if `i` is a character value in the range of `['0'-'9']`, in decimal `[48-57]`.

To check for invalid inputs, you rather want to write

```
  while(cin >> i) {
    sum+=i;
  }
```

Comment: i did use cin>>i , but that did not solve the problem , because that works for EOF as well as invalid character ...    But in this particular problem , you have to check if a character is ever  given as input  , and not print the sum if that happens ... i have tried many approaches , but failed to find a viable solution to the problem

Comment: Read characters (`char`) instead of `int` values then.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    // Get the full line of input
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    // Variables used to loop through your input
    bool failed = false;
    int sum = 0;
    int place = 1;

    // Start from the back keeping track of current place values
    for (int i = line.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (isdigit( line[i] )) {
            // For digits we add the 
            sum +=  place * ((int) line[i] - 48); // Subtract 48 (It gives ASCII)
            place *= 10; // Prepare for next digit
        }
        else if (line[i] == ' ') {
            // Our delimiter
            place = 1; // Prepare for next number
        }
        else {
            // Not a space our a digit
            cout << "invalid Input";
            failed = true;
            break;
        }
    } 
    if (!failed){
        cout << sum;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of a straight `cin`, we use `getline` to take the whole line as input into a string, traverse it backwards, and add digits to our sum.

**As for the question in your title**

In your version, you have a couple problems, but the biggest is that you are running `isdigit` with an integer, and the results you get are not useful. If you want to check if a cast from cin to and int worked correctly, you should use cin's builtin failbit.

For example:

```
int i;
cin >> i;
```

with input:

```
hello
```

Will activate the failbit in cin. You can check for it by using cin as a bool.

The below code :

```
int i;
cin >> i;
while (cin){
    cin >> i;
}
```

will keep putting integers into i until it gets an invalid int like "hello".

This will not however, catch the end of a line, or if the user just presses space bar with no input, and so it is not useful for keeping track of where input ends, because `cin` ignores an empty input, and will just keep waiting. That is why I recommend `getline` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Read a full line, then parse it element by element. To read the line:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(cin, line);
```

To parse it, create a `std::istringstream` and read from that:

```
std::istringstream in(line);
int val;
while (in >> val) {
    // whatever
}
```

And when the loop exits, check **why** it exited:

```
if (in.eof())
    // got through the full line, hit end of file
else
    // stopped short, because something was wrong with the input
```

i